# Закрыть страницы постраничника метатегом <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">

Tags: html, wordpress, seo

На сайте необходимо закрыть страницы постраничника следующим метатегом:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
```

Сайт на WordPress.

Подскажите как мне узнать на каких страница необходимо прописать этот тег и что такое постраничник?

Comment: Постраничник — это, как я понял, постраничная навигация (пагинация). А вот как закрыть — не подскажу — не знаком с Wordpress.

Comment: Спасибо, сам почему то сразу не догадался.

Answer (score 1):

Для необходимых страниц поставил условие:

```
<?php
if(strripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/nggallery/')) {
    echo ('<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow"/>');
}
?>
```

Comment: Почитайте как правильно использовать форматирование и приведите в порядок свой ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help.